# Show that this series show that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\:\frac{\left(n+1\right)^3}{n^4+\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^n}^{\:}\:$ is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I had a question in my textbook that asks me to show that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\:\frac{\left(n+1\right)^3}{n^4+\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^n}^{\:}\:$converges. I tried using ratio test, root test and comparison test but was unable to show it using any of those. How would I go about doing this question?

Comment: What happened when you tried to use those tests?

Comment: You should show your work with more detail.

Comment: Well when I tried ratio test I just cannot get many terms to cancel so it doesn't actually simplify much.

Comment: **Hint :** $$\frac{\left(n+1\right)^3}{n^4+\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^n} = o \left( \dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: how did you get 1/n^2? i was thinking of doing a comparison test where I would compare it by 1/n ( because that is the highest power in the numerator/denominator), but I am not sure how to deal with the power of n.